# Как такое посчитать с помощью Stream API?

Tags: java, потоки-данных

У меня есть большой массив элементов моего класса. В классе есть 2 поля: `String perc` и `String name`. Никак не могу понять как **с помощью Stream API** мне посчитать количество различных `name` для каждого уникального `perc`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
List<Hero> heroes = new ArrayList<>();
heroes.add(new Hero("Alex", "box"));
heroes.add(new Hero("Alex", "box"));
heroes.add(new Hero("Nina", "box"));
heroes.add(new Hero("Lampa", "box"));

heroes.add(new Hero("Alex", "table"));
heroes.add(new Hero("Alex", "table"));
heroes.add(new Hero("Nina", "table"));
heroes.add(new Hero("Lampa", "table"));


Map<String, Map<String, Long>> collect = heroes
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Hero::getPerc, Collectors.groupingBy(Hero::getName, Collectors.counting())));
```

Comment: Cспасибо за ответ!

Comment: @username если ответ верный, то примите его как правильный пожалуйста)